# The v-if filter problem & components render below each other

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-component, vue-directives

I have **two** problematic issues in Vue.js:

1. Filter problem:

I want to fetch the **filtered** records of my API by using v-if.
I do get my records but i cannot find a solution to filter them.

**Question:**
How do I get my articles filtered by the selected option

```
 in the <select v-model> <option>...</
```

2. Components problem:

   Every time I click the button to the detail page of an x article, it just renders the detail_page down below the homepage.
   I do use router, so I navigate using router-links which apparently aren’t working accordingly.

```
I cant use <router-link :to="/"> like that. 
I after some searching i found i can use. 
("' / '") 
<router-link :to="'/'">

OR

<router-link to="/"> 
(without : and ' ')
```

But I think router has less to do with rendering components below each other even when I commented out the Details page.vue in the Homepage.vue. Also, take a look at my code below,

**Question**: How do I make sure that the component that is want to navigate to properly opens on an another page?

```
homepage.vue

<template> 
 <div> <!-- You would have to wrap your list in another element (e.g., a div), making that the root: -->
   <Menu/>
  <div class="jumbotron">
   <form>
<span><strong>Choose your sections below.</strong></span><br>

 <div class="mt-3">
    <select v-model="section">
          <option v-bind:key="section.id" v-for="section in sections" :value="section" @clic="computed_items()">{{ section }}</option>
        </select>
    <div class="mt-3">Selected: <strong>{{ section }}</strong>
      <div class="row mx-auto">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 " v-bind:key="article.id"  v-for="(article, index) in articles.slice(0,10)"  > <!--   to get records you must loop within the div with the for -->


<div v-if="article.section == section" > 
   <b-card v-if="article.multimedia"  
    v-bind:title= "`${article.title}`" 
    v-bind:img-src="`${article.multimedia[0].url}`"
    img-alt="Image"
    img-top
    tag="article"
    style="max-width: 20rem;"
    class="my-4"
  >
 <b-badge href="#" variant="dark">{{article.section}}</b-badge>  <b-badge href="#" variant="light">{{article.subsection}}</b-badge>   
<router-link :to="'/details'"></router-link>
  <hr>
    <b-card-text>
       </b-card-text>
    <b-button variant="primary" @click="goToDetails({index})"> More info   </b-button><br>
   </b-card>
</div>
<div v-else>
  <p>{{article.subsection}} IS NOT {{section}}</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<!-- <Details/> -->
   <!-- <Details v-bind:details="details"/> -->
 </div>
 </template>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="lodash.js"></script>
<script>
//import Details from './Details.vue';
import Menu from './Menu.vue';
 const SECTIONS = "home, arts, automobiles, books, business, fashion, food, health, insider, magazine, movies, national, nyregion, obituaries, opinion, politics, realestate, science, sports, sundayreview, technology, theater, tmagazine, travel, upshot, world"; // From NYTimes
console.log("000"); 
 export default {
    name: "Homepage",
    components: {
     //Details,
      Menu
         },
    props: [
    "articles"
    ], 
    methods: {
      goToDetails(index){
        this.$router.push(`/details/${index["index"]}`).catch(err => {});
        console.log(index);
      },     
    },
      data(){
      return{
      selected: null,
      sections: SECTIONS.split(','), //create an array of sections
      section: 'home', // set default sections to ""home"""
      
      }
   
    }
}

</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    
      <Homepage v-bind:articles="articles" />
      <Details v-bind:articles="articles" />
     <router-view/>
    
  </div>
</template>




<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
import Menu from './components/Menu.vue';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage.vue';
import Details from './components/Details.vue';
import Footer from './components/Footer.vue';



import axios from 'axios';
 var url = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=XXXX';
 
 export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
     Homepage,
    Details,
     Footer,
     Menu
  }, 
  data(){
    return {
      articles: [], // empty array for the api records
     
    }
  },
   created(){
    axios.get(url) 
    //.then(res => this.movies = res.data)
    //.then(res =>console.log(res.data['results']) )
    .then(res => this.articles = res.data['results'])
    // get the Records form the API use Vue detected tool extention via chrome.
  }
}

</script>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
   
    <title>vue_dtt_project_test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but vue_dtt_project_test doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import '@babel/polyfill';
import 'mutationobserver-shim';
import './plugins/bootstrap-vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import {router} from './routes';
import vSelect from 'vue-select';
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';
Vue.component('v-select', vSelect);
window.Vue = Vue; 
 
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
window.Vue = require('vue');

//const routerz = new VueRouter({router});

new Vue({
   router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

router.js

```
// routes.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage.vue';
import Details from './components/Details.vue';
import Footer from './components/Footer.vue';


//import router from './routes';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
//const router = new VueRouter({routes});
export const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'homepage',
      component: Homepage
    },
    {
      path: '/details/:details_id',
      name: 'details',
      component: Details
    },
    {
      path: '/footer',
      name: 'footer',
      component: Footer
    }
  ]

});
```

API data structure

```
articles:Array[54]
  0:Object
     abstract:"The episode also brought to a head tensions in the U.S. attorney’s 
     office in Washington."
     byline:"By Katie Benner, Charlie Savage, Sharon LaFraniere and Ben Protess"
     created_date:"2020-02-12T21:25:28-05:00"
     des_facet:Array[5]
     geo_facet:Array[0]
     item_type:"Article"
     kicker:""
     material_type_facet:""
     multimedia:Array[5]
     org_facet:Array[1]
     per_facet:Array[5]
     published_date:"2020-02-12T21:25:28-05:00"
     section:"us"
     subsection:"politics"
     title:"After Stone Case, Prosecutors Say They Fear Pressure From Trump"
     updated_date:"2020-02-13T09:48:45-05:00" stone-sentencing.html"
  1:Object
  2:Object
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: As you have said it yourself, it's two separate questions: so they should be asked separately.

Comment: It would also make it easier to read if you formatted your code a bit. There's a lot of empty space and indenting is all over the place.

Comment: How do you want to filter the records? If you posted an example of the data structure it would help

Comment: @Still_learning I've added the data structure.

Comment: You are defining **window.Vue** twice in **main.js**: `window.Vue = Vue` and `window.Vue = require('vue');`. That's something not right for sure.